# Understanding this IBD to make a Guess Game in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I am given an assignment of making a guessing game for a Cyclone II FPGA in VHDL.

I have the following IBD diagram about the game:

[image: l]

The purpose of the game is to guess a secret number that the opponent has entered.

The description of the game says the following:

> After entering the guess, a press on a button will evaluate the result
>   as “Hi”, “Lo” or “–”.  The secret number is entered manually by your
>   opponent.
>
> Design a game with an interface as shown in the IBD.
>
> It needs the following functionality:
>
> 1. With no keys pressed, the displays show the current input value.
> 2. With “Set” button pressed, the input value is stored as the secret number.
> 3. With “Show” button pressed, the secret number is displayed.
> 4. With “Try” button pressed, the guess is evaluated and the result is displayed as “Hi”, “Lo” or “–”. The IBD shows the overall building
>      blocks in the design.

**My question is...**

How would it be possible to use the "try" input that goes into the "Compare Logic" entity, when "try" is only a std_logic and not a std_logic_vector to make a guess about a number when it can only be 1 or 0 (on or off)?

Comment: Looks suspiciously like an assignment from my time at Aarhus University ^^

Comment: @JakobHalskov
No one said you can't use StackExchange xD

Comment: Should not be a problem long as it is used for clarifying the question itself. Yet you are encouraged to use your instructor for that first.

Comment: @EugeneSh.
Yes of course. However, we don't have any more lectures before the due date of this assignment, unfortunately.

Comment: I think it depends quite a bit on **how you use** stackexchange. If someone here gave you a significant amount of code, which you then submitted as your own work, I would hope that you would face significant consequences. Now, I'm not saying that is your intent, it's a hypothetical comment.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson
No, it's just a question for clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`try` is a trigger to guess with the input in `input`. `input` has a dual purpose - with `set` it is setting the secret number with `try` it is setting the "guess" number.

In other words, once you press `try`, it will perform the comparison of the value latched in `Latch` and the value given in `input`.

Comment: Ok it makes more sense now.
As an additional question, do you think that the std_logic_vector for "seg" that goes from the two entities "bin2hex" into the biggest mux needs to be 14 bits long or just 7 bits?

Comment: You have two units of `bin2hex` - for each digit. Each digit is represented by 7-seg display - each segment needs a bit.

Comment: So the input in the mux needs to be 14 bits long?

Comment: `try` is an enable that when false makes both P=Q and P>Q outputs of the the magnitude comparator 'Comparator logic' true, a condition that won't occur otherwise. The 4:1 'mux' multiplexer is 14 bits wide. The 'Lo', 'Hi' and '--' inputs are each comprised of two 7 segment values while the last input to 'mux' provides the two 7 segment values for the two hex digit values.

Comment: Yes, looks like it.